# Sourcing methods to an environment different than .GlobalEnv

Tags: r, initialization, masking, robustness

Is it possible to source methods to an environment other than `.GlobalEnv`?

I'm slowly getting a bit frustrated over R's masking mechanism (I'll probably be back with an own question in this respect, but if you're interested, for the moment just try using packages `RMySQL` and `RSQLite` in the same process and loading them in this order; makes my RMySQL stuff crash) and would very very much like to switch to consistently using `<namespace>::foo()` instead of just `foo()` throughout **all** of my scripts.

Yet, using `<namespace>::foo()` is less efficient than using a "local copy" (e.g. `namespace..foo <- <namespace>::foo()`; I can provide examples for those interested, but it's very easy to test for yourself).

Making local copies works a treat for **other** packages I'm loading since (most of them) **do have** a namespace, but before my own code turns "package" it does **not**.

So I though "let's just source my stuff to `NS <- newenv(parent=emptyenv())` and then apply the same routine as for the other packages". But R won't let me:

```
setGeneric(
    name="fooBar",
    signature=c("src"),
    def=function(src, ...){
        standardGeneric("fooBar")    
    }
)
setMethod(
    f="fooBar",
    signature=signature(src="character"),
    definition=function(src, ...){
        cat(src, sep="\n")        
    }
)
# These would go into: 
"Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/gnrc.R"
"Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/mthd.R"

# This works:
source("Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/gnrc.R")
source("Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/mthd.R")

# This does not:
NS <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
source("Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/gnrc.R", local=NS)
source("Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/mthd.R", local=NS)

eval(parse(file="Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/gnrc.R"), envir=NS)
eval(parse(file="Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/mthd.R"), envir=NS)
```

Errors:

```
> source("Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/gnrc.R", local=NS)
Error in eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "setGeneric"
> source("Q:/usr/wsp/3.6.2/32bit/root/_SCRATCH/mthd.R", local=NS)
Error in eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "setMethod"
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG! I'm sorry guys, this is somewhat embarrassing:

I've switched to using `new.env(parent=emptyenv())` consistently in order to prevent some memory ballooning when caching environments and got so used to it that I forgot that it does make sense to have different parent envirs at time ;-)

In this case `NS <- new.env()` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Hadley, I'll check it out